# Get numerical values from document in python

Tags: python

I've extracted the details of a docx file using this code

```
   from docx import Document
   document = Document('136441742-Rental-Agreement-Format.pdf.docx')
   for para in document.paragraphs:
             print(para.text)
```

The output contains numerical values, date and text fields. How to extract numerical values and dates ??

Comment: What have you tried? E.g. checking the cell's format? Take the value of the cell and try to parse it as a number or date?

Comment: Can you please help with the code. I am just a beginner in python

Comment: @Rishav what is the output of the print here?

Comment: Did you try using the function `isdigit()`, on the output to get the numeric value.

Comment: @ Shibu Tewar I think isdigit() is for numerical only, i want to extract also. Can you help me with the code

Comment: I would `.split()` each paragraph,, and check for fragments which look like numbers (easy, `.isdigit()` helps) and dates (can be granrly if date formats are not standardized).

Comment: @Rishav can you add expected output

Comment: @komatiraju The docx file conatins many numerical fields (like 504, 8520 etc), many date fields. I want to extract all of them .

Comment: @aldokkani the ouput of print statement is like this - TENANCY AGREEMENT This Tenancy Agreement is made and executed at Bangalore on this 22.01.2013 by MR .P .RAJA SEKHAR AGED ABOUT 28 YRS S/0.MR.KRISHNA PARAMATMA PENTAKOTA R/at NESTER RAGA B-502, OPP MORE MEGA STORE BANGALORE-560 048 Hereinafter called the 'OWNER' of the One Part. AND MR.VENKATA BHYRAVA MURTHY MUTNURI & P/at NO.17-2-16, l/EERABHARAPURAM AGED ABOUT 26 YRS RAOAHMUNDRY ANDHRA PRADESH S/n.MR.RAGHAVENDRA RAO 533105 –

Comment: @Rishav i get what you are saying but some numbers are part of string ex: street number etc. What about that? It is easy if you add expected output

Comment: @komatiraju let me explain my problem in brief. I've a docx format file. It is bascially a rental agreement of flat. It contains a lot of text, numerical values and date. I just have to extract 3 things here. First one is all the dates mentioned in docx. Secondly, All the numerical terms mentioned in docx (even some numbers are part of string ex: street number etc). Third one is that few text are mentioned in docx is underlined. that also i need. these 3 fields i need to extract. Hence i am a beginer in python, i am not   getting how to code it

Answer (score 0):

Using the document output you had shared in the comment, using the data as a string, and assuming the date format is dd.mm.yyy, and does not changes, I wrote the below code to get the date and numerical values, and it works fine for me.
I am using regular expression to extract date and `isdigit()` to get numerical values.
you could adopt the below code to work on your exact document output if needed.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
text = "TENANCY AGREEMENT This Tenancy Agreement is made and executed at Bangalore on this 22.01.2013 by MR .P .RAJA SEKHAR AGED ABOUT 28 YRS S/0.MR.KRISHNA PARAMATMA PENTAKOTA R/at NESTER RAGA B-502, OPP MORE MEGA STORE BANGALORE-560 048 Hereinafter called the 'OWNER' of the One Part. AND MR.VENKATA BHYRAVA MURTHY MUTNURI & P/at NO.17-2-16, l/EERABHARAPURAM AGED ABOUT 26 YRS RAOAHMUNDRY ANDHRA PRADESH S/n.MR.RAGHAVENDRA RAO 533105"
a=[]

match = re.search(r'\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}', text)
date = datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%d.%m.%Y').date()
print(date)
for i in text :
    if i.isdigit() == True:
        a.append(i)


print(a)
```

Output -

```
2013-01-22
['2', '2', '0', '1', '2', '0', '1', '3', '2', '8', '0', '5', '0', '2', '5', '6', '0', '0', '4', '8', '1', '7', '2', '1', '6', '2', '6', '5', '3', '3', '1', '0', '5']
```

Comment: i don't want to add text to variable manually like text = "TENANCY AGREEMENT ...". I want it to directly read from docx file and give me the output

Comment: @Rishav I understand that is why, I gave that as an example to address your issue, you could use the code example and work on your file, as I don't know how exactly the file looks, if there is any line breaks etc.

Comment: let me explain my problem in brief. I've a docx format file. It is bascially a rental agreement of flat. It has many line breaks. It contains a lot of text, numerical values and date. I just have to extract 3 things here. First one is all the dates mentioned in docx. All the numerical terms mentioned in docx (even some numbers are part of string ex: street number etc). Third one is that few text are mentioned in docx is underlined. that also i need. these 3 fields i need to extract. Hence i am a beginer in python, i am not  getting how to code it

Comment: @Rishav Though I would like to help you, but its difficult for me to write code without the actual file, there is no point in getting the code wrong based on assumptions. Would be great if you spend some effort to see how to use the code I had shared, though I understand you are a beginner but it is worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the numbers using `regex`

`\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}` this will find the date

`\d+-\d+-\d+` this will find plot number

`\d{3} ?\d{3}` this will find pincodes

`\d+` this will find all other numbers

To find underline text you can use docx [run.underline](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.run.Run.underline) property

```
for para in Document('test.docx').paragraphs:
     nums = re.findall('\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}|\d+-\d+-\d+|\d{3} ?\d{3}|\d+', para.text)
     underline_text = [run.text for run in para.runs if run.underline]
```